# Jcarousel how to re-execute connector function?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Using great jcarousel connected carousels plugin, so to execute it using this file https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/blob/master/examples/connected-carousels/jcarousel.connected-carousels.js, as you see

```
$(function() {
        // Setup the carousels. Adjust the options for both carousels here.
        var carouselStage      = $('.carousel-stage').jcarousel();
        var carouselNavigation = $('.carousel-navigation').jcarousel();
```

initializes `jcarousel()`, it's working great, but i'm inserting new images on `carousel-stage`  and `carousel-navigation` on the fly, and on new images the effects are not being applied, how to reinitialize this function on file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you append your new pictures, just call the "destroy" method ( http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/api.html#destroy ) and restart the pluggin calling

```
var carouselStage      = $('.carousel-stage').jcarousel();
var carouselNavigation = $('.carousel-navigation').jcarousel();
```

back again. SO:

```
// Destroy
// Add images
// Rebuild
```

Comment: how to rebuild it, because just calling `$('.carousel-navigation').jcarousel();` won't do the job, as there're other callbacks to call?

Comment: the same way you built it at first :)

Comment: i'm just attaching this file https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/blob/master/examples/connected-carousels/jcarousel.connected-carousels.js on my html page, and it's being loaded on document.reload

Comment: You will have to change this a little bit. Like adding the actions into a function (instead of "(function($) {" or "dom ready") and call it manually, so that you can rebuild the carousel anytime you want.

Comment: thanks anyway, i'll accept your answer, just created function with that code, and initialized it on appropriate place